# Entity framework select single subcategory

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I have catalog table with
Id
Name
Parent_id with null type

I want to select single subcategory path with unlimited parents
Like home 》 catalog 》 subcategory 》 subcategory 1 》 ...... 》

Already i used join but it's have some limited because need to know how many sub need to use

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and look to include an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Already i searched and i didn't found the answer that's why i asked